# How to query jsonb data as json

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-data-jpa, jsonb

I want to query a row from Postgres where Value column is :-

Value column is of type jsonb

```json
{"Id": "SingleRecord",  "CreatedAtUtc": "2021-07-13T05:50:36.5710801", "_masterSecretId": "Dummy-MasterSecret", "_useMessageTypesHttps": false}
```

But, when I query, it is retrieved as:

```
{Id=SingleRecord, CreatedAtUtc=2021-07-13T05:50:36.5710801, _masterSecretId=Dummy-MasterSecret, _useMessageTypesHttps=false}
```

I don't want the equal sign and I want the quotations?

### How to get that?

Data in Postgres db :-

```
 4739 | SingleRecord                         | AF.ProvisioningRecord   | z6MkqYJNSCMqzTd7AZcSFExM4EvYJLsVZQ7vn3PvFoVSKpTb | {"Id": "SingleRecord", "Owner": {"Name": "did:dtx:z6MkqYJNSCMqzTd7AZcSFExM4EvYJLsVZQ7vn3PvFoVSKpTb", "Role": "issuer"}, "Endpoint": {"did": "did:dtx:z6MkqYJNSCMqzTd7AZcSFExM4EvYJLsVZQ7vn3PvFoVSKpTb", "uri": "http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/sharedagent/endpoint?identifier=C63Kqx7Qev8e44mjZfzWD9NYUmbe9Wsa62UzRXXRQbgD-issuer", "verkey": ["C63Kqx7Qev8e44mjZfzWD9NYUmbe9Wsa62UzRXXRQbgD"]}, "CreatedAtUtc": "2021-07-13T05:50:36.5710801", "_masterSecretId": "Dummy-MasterSecret", "_useMessageTypesHttps": false}
```

This is the function that is doing the main call to postgres:-

```
@Query("select r from NonSecretRecordEntity r where r.id=:id and r.userIdentifier=:useridentifier and r.typeName=:type ORDER BY r.recordid desc")
List<NonSecretRecordEntity> findUserTypeNameById(@Param("id") String id, @Param("useridentifier") String useridentifier, @Param("type") String typename);
```

Comment: JPA probably converted that to a Map and the output you are seeing is the default `toString()` of a such a map. How exactly are you getting that output? Is the String representation actually  a problem? Do you get wrong values when you access the content of the Map?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, The string representation is a problem. I want the query as :-   {"Id": "SingleRecord",  "CreatedAtUtc": "2021-07-13T05:50:36.5710801", "_masterSecretId": "Dummy-MasterSecret", "_useMessageTypesHttps": false}                                                    without equal to sign (=) and with double quotes (")

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question add add the Java code that shows your problem with the format of the `toString()` method of a `Map`

Comment: So what data type is used in `NonSecretRecordEntity` to store the JSON value? How do you access the content of that variable?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, So, we are talking about the 5th column here. And that variable is of Object Type inside NonSecretRecordEntity Class and the corresponding column is of jsonb type in postgres db.

Comment: And what _concrete_ class is that value at runtime? How is that column mapped in your `@Entity` class?

Comment: @NotNull
    @Type(type = "JsonbType")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb")
    private Object value;                                                                                                                    This is the Value variable defined inside the class

Comment: public class JsonbType implements UserType {

    private final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); }                                             And this is the JsonbType Class.

Comment: Java code belongs into the **question** and not into comments. But if you are using Jackson's ObjectMapper the values should be converted into a `Map` which brings us back to the question (that you still haven't answered): **how** do you access that map?

Comment: Actually, That variable is not a map and it is of Object Type

Comment: @HarshMultani you can use the objectMapper to read it as Json string from MAP.
In the setter of your POJO just change that to String using objectMapper